# LINQ OrderBy with more than one field

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list that I need sorted by two fields.  I've tried using OrderBy in LINQ but that only allows me to specify one field.  I'm looking for the list to be sorted by the first field and then if there are any duplicates in the first field to sort by the second field.

For example I want the results to look like this (sorted by last name then first name).

- Adams, John
- Smith, James
- Smith, Peter
- Thompson, Fred

I've seen that you can use the [SQL like syntax to accomplish this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499621/multiple-orderby-in-this-linq-code) but I am looking for a way to do it with the OrderBy method.

```
IList<Person> listOfPeople = /*The list is filled somehow.*/
IEnumerable<Person> sortedListOfPeople = listOfPeople.OrderBy(aPerson => aPerson.LastName, aPerson.FirstName); //This doesn't work.
```

Answer (score 195, accepted):

You need to use [`ThenBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534743.aspx):

```
listOfPeople.OrderBy(person => person.LastName)
            .ThenBy(person => person.FirstName)
```

Comment: A full explanation is listed here: http://weblogs.asp.net/zeeshanhirani/archive/2008/04/16/thenby-operator-part-14.aspx

Comment: This is Lambda .. LINQ solution need @svick has it in LINQ.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Query syntax is just sugar for the method syntax above; both are "LINQ". See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397947.aspx  
And if you read the question, he's specifically asking for the method syntax version.

Answer (score 31):

If you want to use method syntax, use [`ThenBy()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534743.aspx), as others suggested:

```
listOfPeople.OrderBy(person => person.LastName)
            .ThenBy(person => person.FirstName)
```

In query syntax, the same can be accomplished pretty much the way you wanted: two sort keys separated by a comma:

```
from person in listOfPeople
orderby person.LastName, person.FirstName
select person
```

The above code will be actually compiled to code that uses `OrderBy()` and `ThenBy()`, as in the first example.

Also, if you'd like to have `OrderBy()` that takes two (or more) sort keys, you can certainly write that as an extension method on `IEnumerable<T>` that internally calls `OrderBy()` and `ThenBy()`.

Answer (score 3):

Your subsequent fields should be ordered by using the ThenBy() method

Answer (score 3):

The way to order a list with more filed is the follow:

```
var soterdList = initialList.OrderBy(x => x.Priority).
                                    ThenBy(x => x.ArrivalDate).
                                    ThenBy(x => x.ShipDate);
```

You can add other fields with clasole "ThenBy"

Answer (score 2):

Use `.ThenBy(aPerson=>field2);`

Answer (score 2):

```
var sortedListOfPeople = listOfPeople.OrderBy(aPerson => aPerson.LastName).ThenBy(a => aPerson.FirstName);
```