# How to order by with 2 field

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I use Entity Frameword and want to list objects sorted by 2 field. my expression is below :

```
TbCusromers.OrderBy(x->x.Family, x.Name);
```

How can I sort my list order by Family & Name?

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ OrderBy with more than one field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047455/linq-orderby-with-more-than-one-field)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
TbCusromers.OrderBy(x=>x.Family).ThenBy(x=>x.Name);
```

Answer (score 1):

Whilst I've upvoted the above answer, you may also want to consider this.

```
TbCusromers.OrderBy( x=> x.Family + x.Name )
```

This will allow you to sort by a concatenated version of the two fields.