# Correct this LINQ instruction syntax

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, list

I list the files of a directory and I sort it by the file extension:

```
Dim Files As List(Of IO.FileInfo) = Get_Files(Directory, True, ValidExtensions).OrderBy(Function(x) x.Extension).ToList
```

How I can add in the same instruction another parameter to sort it also by the name content like this?:

```
x.Name.ToLower.Contains("word")
```

I've tried to separate it with a comma (yes, so stupid):

```
Dim Files As List(Of IO.FileInfo) = Get_Files(Directory, True, ValidExtensions).OrderBy(Function(x) x.Extension, x.Name.ToLower.Contains("word")).ToList
```

> ```
> UPDATE
> ```

I've tried to use the @p.s.w.g solution but does not return the desired result.

But if I make two lists by separate I get the desired sort in the second list:

```
 Dim Files As List(Of IO.FileInfo) = _
Get_Files(Directory, True, ValidExtensions).OrderBy(Function(x) x.Extension).ToList

Dim Files2 As List(Of IO.FileInfo) = _
Files.OrderBy(Function(x) x.Name.ToLower.Contains("word")).ToList
```

But I want to improve it doing it only in the first list.

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ OrderBy with more than one field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047455/linq-orderby-with-more-than-one-field)

Comment: @ppejovic in that solutions shows the usage of the ThenBy method but I've updated my question saying that method does not return the desired result for me, then now isn't a duplicate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`ThenBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534743.aspx) method:

```
Dim Files As List(Of IO.FileInfo) = _
    Get_Files(Directory, True, ValidExtensions) _
        .OrderBy(Function(x) x.Extension) _
        .ThenBy(Function(x) x.Name.ToLower.Contains("word")) _
        .ToList
```

**Update** to have all the items which do not contain `"word"` in their name come first, use this:

```
Dim Files As List(Of IO.FileInfo) = _
    Get_Files(Directory, True, ValidExtensions) _
        .OrderBy(Function(x) x.Name.ToLower.Contains("word")) _
        .ThenBy(Function(x) x.Extension) _
        .ToList
```

Of course you can always swap `OrderBy` with `OrderByDescending` and `ThenBy` with `ThenByDescending` to revers the order of a single sort key if necessary.

Comment: Thanks but I've tried the code and does not return the desired sort, please see my update.

Comment: ouch, simply as changing the properties order... thanks again.