# Linq to SQL sort by fields in 2 entities (parent-child)

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I have 2 entities called Request and Days. Request has many days and what I am having problems with is properly sorting my entities the way I want to.

Days has a certain field called Hours and I need to sort it first by the Hours field in days (however, first are ALL of the fields that have only one day) and then, by then number of Days in a Request.

I've tried many orderby/thenby combinations and can't get this quite right.

Here is a recent one I've tried:

```
sortingFunction = x => x.Days.OrderBy(h => h.Hours).Count();
```

Any help with this?

Comment: use "ThenBy" after "OrderBy" : http://stackoverflow.com/a/3047467/1380061

Comment: It's not clear how you going to sort requests by hours in days. Each request have many days. Do you want to sort by sum of hours, or by average hour, or min hour?

Comment: ThenBy and OrderBy doesn't work, probably because this is on different entities. @SergeyBerezovskiy each Day has a hours field and I need to sort this ascendingly where the number of days in a request is 1, after that it sorts by number of days in a request (I used Count() for this earlier)

Comment: still unclear what you want to do, show us more code.

Comment: Which part of code would be helpful in this context? I need to get a sorted list of requests which are sorted the way I mentioned. var reqs  = db.Requests.OrderBy(..); I need a proper query to put inside order so that it sorts by the rules I explained? Since a request has one or more days, days has a field called hours, I need to sort this so the first elements are all of the requests that have one day and are sorted ascending by hours, after that, come all the request with more than one request in ascending order so basically it's sorted from least hours to most days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from r in db.Requests
let daysCount = r.Days.Count()
orderby daysCount == 1 ? r.Days.FirstOrDefault().Hours : Int32.MaxValue, 
        daysCount
select r
```

Generated SQL query will look like:

```
SELECT
[Project4].[Id] AS [Id],
[Project4].[Foo] AS [Foo]
FROM ( SELECT
    CASE WHEN ((1 = [Project3].[C1]) AND ([Project3].[C1] IS NOT NULL)) 
         THEN [Project3].[C2] ELSE 2147483647 END AS [C1],
    [Project3].[Id] AS [Id],
    [Project3].[Foo] AS [Foo]
    [Project3].[C1] AS [C2]
    FROM ( SELECT
        [Project1].[Id] AS [Id],
        [Project1].[Foo] AS [Foo]
        [Project1].[C1] AS [C1], // count of days
        (SELECT TOP (1) // C2 is hours of first day
            [Extent3].[Hours] AS [Hours]
            FROM [dbo].[Days] AS [Extent3]
            WHERE [Project1].[Id] = [Extent3].[RequestId]) AS [C2]
        FROM (SELECT
            [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id],
            [Extent1].[Foo] AS [Foo]
            (SELECT
                COUNT(1) AS [A1]
                FROM [dbo].[Days] AS [Extent2]
                WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[RequestId]) AS [C1]
            FROM [dbo].[Requests] AS [Extent1]
        )  AS [Project1]
    )  AS [Project3]
)  AS [Project4]
ORDER BY [Project4].[C1] ASC, [Project4].[C2] ASC
```