# C# - Return record which has the lowest PayDate but also the highest ReconciliationDate

Tags: c#, linq

So I need to pull the record which matches the following criteria:

A record which has the lowest PayDate but also the highest ReconciliationDate. 
An example of records can be seen like this

```
public class Data {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime PayDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReconciliationDate { get; set; }
}

--------------------------------------------------
| Name   | PayDate    | ReconciliationDate       |
--------------------------------------------------
| Andrew | 11/14/2018 | 07/01/2018               |
--------------------------------------------------
| Andrew | 10/14/2018 | 06/01/2018               |
--------------------------------------------------
| Andrew | 05/14/2018 | 08/01/2018               |
--------------------------------------------------
| Andrew | 05/14/2018 | 03/01/2018               |
--------------------------------------------------
| Andrew | 05/14/2018 | 10/01/2018               |
```

So the correct record to be returned would be #5

How can I achieve this using C#?

I have this so far:

```
    var recordsNextCouponPaymentAfterLastOfMonth = externalInterestForSecurity.Where(aExternalRecord => aExternalRecord.PayDate > priorMonthEnd);
```

Comment: You could sort the list with `OrderBy`, `OrderByDescending`, `ThenBy`, and/or `ThenByDescending`, then take the first row. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047455/linq-orderby-with-more-than-one-field).

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the LINQ methods `OrderBy` and `ThenBy`

In your case its

```
.OrderBy(x => x.PayDate).ThenByDescending(x => x.ReconciliationDate).First
```

Comment: Select first one I think

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto what do you mean half the answer? it's exactly what he needs.