# Sort a list in C# by custom index and sameness

Tags: c#

I have some large files (5000+ line items) with brief information of hardware parts.

Put simply, each part has an Id and name, and all parts from a file are added to a `List` collection, like:

```cs
void Main()
{
    var parts = new List<dynamic>();

    parts.Add(make(1, "Part A"));
    parts.Add(make(2, "Part B"));
    parts.Add(make(3, "Part C"));
    parts.Add(make(4, "Part D"));
    parts.Add(make(5, "Part A"));
    parts.Add(make(6, "Part E"));
    parts.Add(make(7, "Part B"));
    parts.Add(make(8, "Part F"));
    parts.Add(make(9, "Part G"));
    parts.Add(make(10, "Part B"));
}

dynamic make(int id, string name)
{
    dynamic o = new ExpandoObject();

    o.id = id;
    o.name = name;

    return o;
}
```

This list of parts is sorted, first by a custom sorting order of part Ids (determined separately) available as a `List` of Ids:

```cs
var customOrderPartIds = new List<int>() { 10, 8, 6, 4, 2, 9, 7, 5, 3, 1 };

parts.OrderBy(p => customOrderPartIds.IndexOf(p.id)).ToList();
```

```
/*
This gives the needed order:

10 - Part B
8 - Part F
6 - Part E
4 - Part D
2 - Part B
9 - Part G
7 - Part B
5 - Part A
3 - Part C
1 - Part A
*/
```

Now, the second ordering I need is for same part names to be together, but keeping the first ordering intact, and a part group increment number:

```
/*
This is the needed final order, along with an increment:

10 - Part B - 1
2 - Part B - 1
7 - Part B - 1
8 - Part F - 2
6 - Part E - 3
4 - Part D - 4
9 - Part G - 5
5 - Part A - 6
1 - Part A - 6
3 - Part C - 7
*/
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LINQ OrderBy with more than one field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047455/linq-orderby-with-more-than-one-field)

Comment: You can chain ordering by using OrderBy(e => e.Property).ThenBy(e => e.OtherProperty)

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, it doesn't help. If I use `ThenBy` and do something like `parts.OrderBy(p => customOrderPartIds.IndexOf(p.id)).ThenBy(p => p.name).ToList();`, the results don't reflect the second ordering as I need it (sample output above).

Comment: Why you use `dynamic` at all and not a class with a property `Id` and `Name`? Even a `ValueTuple<int, id>` was much better than dynamic.

Comment: @TimSchmelter It's just to keep this question simple and brief.

Comment: @Nick: don't use dynamic to simplify your questions, that will raise other issues not related to your question then.

Comment: Invert the order of the parameters, i.e. first order by name, and then by costomOrderPartIds.

Comment: @JonasH Doesn't work as required (sample output above).

Comment: Depending on your performance requirements, you might stream the files and build your result without linq, to avoid caching all the entries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could group it, and output again.

```cs
var result = parts.OrderBy(p => customOrderPartIds.IndexOf(p.id))
             .GroupBy(x => x.name)
             .SelectMany(x => x);
```

Comment: Missing the increment number but it's simple to add

Answer (score 1):

Something like that should do as second ordering:

```
parts = parts.SelectMany(
    item => parts.First(p => p.Name == item.Name) == item ? 
        parts.Where(p => p.Name == item.Name) : new List<dynamic>()).ToList();
```

If it is the first one of the group: return all items of the group.